# Truncate all numbers in a string to one decimal except in certain circumstances

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am currently formatting strings in this way:

```
import re    
res = re.sub(r'\d+\.\d{1,}', lambda m: format(float(m.group(0)), '.1f'), res)
```

This truncates all numbers to one decimal point. I'd like to put an exception in here, that it should only do so if the number is not followed by the letter `l`. For example, `'Yesterday I drank 8.567 coke bottles of 0.85L'` would be formatted to `'Yesterday I drank 8.5 coke bottles of 0.85L`

Still struggling with regex...

Answer (score 3):

```
import re    
res = re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+(?![lL\d])', lambda m: format(float(m.group(0)), '.1f'), res)
#                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/8J5cxs/1)

Comment: Wouldn't this match `0.8` out of `0.85L` though? You probably need to end the pattern with a `\b`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain the regex in your answer please? It seems to shorten numbers ending with L to two decimals rather than just leaving them as long as they are. Why is this so?

Comment: @Lugo - do you know http://regex101.com ? Paste any regex inside and you get (on the right side) an explanation of the pattern. You can also test the regex against different text you input into the lower text input field. You can also try substitution, but only against normal text, not python code :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: Yes, you're perfectly right. Fixed.And I give you my vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

The current answer [fails](https://rextester.com/YVYY86582) for inputs such as `0.8885L`. You can use the following:

```
import re
res = re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+(?![L\d])', lambda m: format(float(m.group(0)), '.1f'), res, flags=re.I)
```

**Changes made to your regex:**

- Replaced `{1,}` with `+` as they do the same thing.
- Added a [negative Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?![L\d])`, which means "not followed by the letter L or a digit".
- Added the flag `re.I`, which means "Ignore case".

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/AXEYQ71354).**

Note: If you don't want to apply the `re.I` flag, you can use the following pattern instead:

```
\d+\.\d+(?![Ll\d])
```